# SQL Query Dates Between FInancial Period Start and Selected Date

Tags: sql-server, date

I have a crystal report with this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT T0.DocNum, T0.TaxDate, T2.OcrName, T1.U_Field_Wt, T1.Quantity, T3.CCTypeCode
FROM OIGN T0 INNER JOIN IGN1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry]
INNER JOIN OOCR T2 ON T1.[OcrCode] = T2.[OcrCode]
INNER JOIN OPRC T3 ON T1.[OcrCode] = T3.[PrcCode]
WHERE T0.TaxDate BETWEEN {?StartDate} AND {?EndDate}
```

I have a company whose financial period starts on April 1st every year ending on March 31st the next year.

I want to modify it such that the query takes only one paramater, ie. `{?EndDate}` and returns results based on start date being the financial period start and end date being any date entered. Thus showing year to date results. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@startdate = DATEADD(YEAR, 
              (CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM, @enddate) <= 3 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END), 
              CONVERT(DATE, CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), DATEPART(YEAR, @enddate)) + '-04-01'));
```

Or,

```
@startdate = CONVERT(DATE,
              CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), 
               DATEPART(YEAR, @enddate) - 
                (CASE WHEN DATEPART(MM, @enddate) <= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) + '-04-01');
```